# UIViewController have no parentViewController with UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I use `UIStoryboardSegue`

```
- (void)perform
{
    [(UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [(UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [(UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then in `destinationViewController` value for `parentViewController` is `nil`. How it possible, and how to get `sourceViewController` in `destinationViewController` using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation. Going from your code sniplet, `parentViewController` should be `nil` because it is not imbedded in a containter view of its parentView. 
Did you mean `presentingViewController`?

Ahh... It changed with iOS 5. In earler versions `parentViewController` did return the presenting view controller if it did not have a parent. Now it returns nil. You should use `preseningViewController` instead.